# active admin Internationalization (I18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

I wan't to add language selection to choose between original (English) and my native language (latvian). I followed this  [hint](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#internationalization_i18n)

There are written that I have to copy lib/active_admin/locales/en.yml  to config/locales, but I can't find that en.yml file. I searched over all my project. I have used this command `rails generate active_admin:assets` . Also tried to download it from Github, but without success, there is no such folder locales. So I am stuck. Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you're looking for is here

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/config/locales

I think this how to is outdated.

Comment: Thanks, but where then I can find appropriate tutorial to add new language ?

Comment: Isn't `lv.yml` Latvian? You should not have to copy the file, just set app default locale to Latvian.

Comment: That is latvian, but Is there any chance to set up selection off desired language ? LIke at the top off the page is ENG and LV symbols, clicking on them that changes language?

Comment: I followed Rails Guides for that, in my setup I detect lang (in order) from session, browser Accept Language and then fallback to default (en). Choice is saved in session (to cut headers parsing time on subsequent requests) and when user clicks a flag-link I have an action to change value stored in session. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
$ bundle show activeadmin
```

Once you know where the Gem is installed, you'll find all the locales in a path like this one:

```
...gems/active_admin-e7ef9a8f3e0e/config/locales/
```